# bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null at Scope.moveBindingTo

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-ios

I've updated react native to 0.59.5 and am getting this error:

```
bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:864:13)
    at convertBlockScopedToVar (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:139:13)
    at PluginPass.VariableDeclaration (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:26:9)
    at newFn (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
```

Ive seen solutions to upgrade `babel-preset-react-native` to 5.0.2. I've done that and it didn't work. Another solution was to use `metro-react-native-babel-preset` instead. That didn't work either. Another solution was to use `@babel/preset-env`. That didn't work either. I even commented out the code that the error is complaining about so I don't even know how it is giving the same error on that commented out line of code now...Any ideas?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vepo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "flow-typed": "^2.4.0",
    "generator-rn-toolbox": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.9",
    "list": "^2.0.15",
    "metro-bundler": "^0.22.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.12",
    "react-native-git-upgrade": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-interactable": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.100",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.31",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-redux-router": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.8",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2",
    "yoga": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.75.0",
    "plist": "^2.1.0",
    "react-devtools": "^3.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "remotedev-server": "^0.2.4",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I restarted my computer it worked.

code that worked:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vepo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "flow-typed": "^2.4.0",
    "generator-rn-toolbox": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.9",
    "list": "^2.0.15",
    "metro-bundler": "^0.22.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "native-base": "2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.12",
    "react-native-git-upgrade": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-interactable": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.100",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.31",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-redux-router": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.8",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2",
    "yoga": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.75.0",
    "plist": "^2.1.0",
    "react-devtools": "^3.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "remotedev-server": "^0.2.4",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```